# logical error with calculating download consumption

Tags: python, performance, monitoring, psutil, speed-test

I wrote this code to calculate my internet consumption starting from the time it is started,
but it seems to give large number that did not express the real consumption, I could not figure out where I made mistake
So why is it doing this, is there any logical error??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing it in bytes then it will be big won't it? because bytes are a small measurement. if you divide new_total by 1000 then print it, it will be in kilobytes, again and you get megabytes then gigabytes.

I would divide it by 1000000

Comment: no I am using a function that specify the proper unit for me, but the issue is that it  gives me a consumption larger than the real one even when I make the unit conversion. for example in one minute a total consumption of 10kBytes or in one our 50GBytes this function                                                                                                                                  def get_size(bytes):
    for unit in ['B','KB','MB','GB','TB','PB']:
        if bytes < 1024:
            return f'{bytes:.2f}{unit}'
        else:
            bytes = bytes/1024

Comment: Oh, well sorry i have no idea

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).